# Load text+pdf file in uiwebview

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I want to show some text and pdf file in a webview at a time.

is there any possibility..

i had tried using

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>some text which i need to show above pdf</p><img src=\"file://%@\">",@"FR.pdf"];
NSString *bundleP = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundleP];
[pdfWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:fileURL];
```

This shows the text and only the first page of pdf file,..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use another way to load pdf and above the `webView` add a `UILabel` to show the text. As you see pdf is treated as a `image` so that only one page is showed.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FR" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePathURL]];
```

Comment: actually, the client dont want me use label. due to memory allocation issue

Comment: I don't think doing this will cause memory issue,anyway it is your client.